# setup 301 redirect for post slug change

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I'm looking at moving from [Wordpress to Octopress](http://mattgemmell.com/2011/09/12/blogging-with-octopress/) but I'm extremely skeptical about the whole post-slug url management. My current blog handles urls in this fashion:

```
myblog.com/post-id/post-slug
e.g.:
journal.kaush.co/283/recommended-mac-os-x-software-2011-2012
```

I understand Octopress has a url scheme as follows:

```
myblog.com/YYYY/MM/DD/post-slug
```

So if i have to setup 301 redirects, will this have to be done manually for every single page, or is there a more intelligent way to approach this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking cue from Virtual Vagabond, i went the .htaccess route. Fortunately,another good soul on the internet has written a script for this. You can find the [ruby script used to generate the .htaccess file here](https://gist.github.com/2782304).

Answer (score 1):

Update permalink structure first ( [check this one](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)) and use 301 redirect using [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-301-redirects/) plugin.

Comment: hmm but since these redirects are wordpress plugins, the minute i move to octopress these plugins are going to stop working thus stopping the redirects? or is there some apache magic being persisted though these plugins?

Comment: Well, you can also add rewrite rules in .htaccess, but I personally don't like to make the file too heavy, because a little mistake can return 500 internal server or reduce overall performance etc.

Comment: hmm.. so i guess i will have to do this manually? it would be awesome to have the wordpress plugin make the .htaccess for me, and then i simply plug that in after migration. Could you add a sample .htaccess file on how a sample redirect would be done, i can then mark your response as an answer. Cheers.